# how to to typecast CIMValue with integer?

Tags: java, authorize.net-cim

in my code i need to compare CIMValue with integer. here i am unable to typecast it.

```
 CIMValue op ;
 if(op ! = 0 || 4096) // here i need to validate whether CIMValue is 0 or 4096
```

**// ERROR : Incompatible operand types CIMValue and int**

Comment: use if(op !=0 && op==4096)

Comment: The error is quite obvious as you are trying to compare to completely different types. Check if there is any integer representation of `CIMValue` object and do comparison on that.

Comment: Maybe this one: http://sblim.sourceforge.net/cim-client-doc/org/sblim/wbem/cim/CIMValue.html  In which case there is a getValue() that might return a Number, so you can do intValue().

Comment: You asked your question without enough information, so I down-vote it.

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh i am very new to coding as well as i'm new to java(sblim).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try this

```
        int iValue = (Integer)op.getValue();
        if(iValue ! = 0 || iValue ! = 4096)
```

Comment: `The value of the local variable iValue is never used.`, haha :)

Answer (score 0):

If `CIMValue` overrides `equals(...)`, use:

```
if(!op.equals(0) || !op.equals(4096))
```

Or maybe:

```
int i = op.getValue() //????
if(i != 0 || i != 4096)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to [SBLIM](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/sblim/index.php?title=Main_Page), so:

```
Object value = op.getValue();
if (value instanceof Number) {
    if (value.equals(0) || value.equals(4096)) {
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: better use ((Number)value).intValue(). Who knows how/if equals works.

Comment: What if the value is a double? then intValue() will cast it and loose precision.

Answer (score -1):

Try it

```
int value = (Integer)op.getValue();

if(value  ! = 0 || value  != 4096){
}
```

Comment: This is also one problem which you have solved but this is not a  main problem actually